# Create 6 monthly periods in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataset (lets just call it `df`) containing a populated `ID column` and a date column called `Start_of_Intervention`.

I'm trying to calculate `6 month periods` for a period of 5 years before and after this `Start_of_Intervention` date.

`The dates are formatted as 20/02/2015 etc.`

I think I need to use `datetime.date` as I'm not interested in the time part, but am having trouble linking my dataset to any of the date functions.

This code does not seem to work well:

```
dt['START_OF_INTERVENTION2']=dt['START_OF_INTERVENTION'].astype(str) 

dt['START_OF_INTERVENTION3'] = dt['START_OF_INTERVENTION2'].apply( 
lambda x: 
x+relativedelta(months=+6)
```

Can anyone advise please?

Comment: Welcome you to StackOverflow, Please edit your question and follow the instructions [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),
to get an answer to your question

Comment: Please share sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid mixing regular Python types with Pandas. A considerable amount of Pandas `datetime` functionality is available, tested and documented. For example, you can use `pd.DateOffset` after converting your series to `datetime`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE0': ['30/01/2015', '20/02/2015', '10/03/2015']})

df['DATE0'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE0'], dayfirst=True)

# ALTERNATIVE 1
df = df.join(pd.concat((df['DATE0'].add(pd.DateOffset(months=6*i)).rename(f'DATE{i}') \
                        for i in range(1, 5)), axis=1))

# ALTERNATIVE 2
df = df.assign(**{f'DATE{i}': df['DATE0'].add(pd.DateOffset(months=6*i)) \
                  for i in range(1, 5)})

print(df)

       DATE0      DATE1      DATE2      DATE3      DATE4
0 2015-01-30 2015-07-30 2016-01-30 2016-07-30 2017-01-30
1 2015-02-20 2015-08-20 2016-02-20 2016-08-20 2017-02-20
2 2015-03-10 2015-09-10 2016-03-10 2016-09-10 2017-03-10
```

Comment: Thank you. I have edited 'Alternative 2' to encompass the full pre and post 5 year periods.